# link click(): jQuery function body not reached 

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to align the height of a sidebar div by the height of another div, accessed (show/hide) by clicking on a link. The solution I've implemented so far is to attach a function to each click, and set $('').height(height) for the sidebar div. 'Course, it doesn't work in IE7, although it's great in IE8 and firefox.

JS code:

```
     function BindResizeSideBar() {
        $('div#containerFloat div#tabs-box a').each ( function() {
            var targetId = this.getAttribute('href');
            if($('div#' + targetId).length == 0) return;
            $(this).bind('click', function() {
                var height = $('div#' + targetId).height() + 90;
                alert(targetId + ', ' + height);
                $('div#divSavedSearchesSideBar div.leftSide').height(height);
            });
        });
        // init: click on tabProfile;
        $('div#containerFloat div#tabs-box a[href=#tabProfile]').click();
    }
```

HTML structure:

```
<div#content-side.searchProspects>
    <div#sidebar style="float: left; width: 15%;">
    <div#divTabContainer>
        <div#header>
        <div#containerFloat>
            <div#tabs-box>
            <div#tabContent1>
            <div#tabContent2>
            ...
            <div#tabContent6>
```

Comment: Does your HTML *actually look like that*?

Comment: The HTML doesn't actually look like that; this is the short version of its structure. The HTML is actually some 3 pages long, and made from 5 different ascx-es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two more alert instructions later, and the problem was found. In IE7, `this.getAttribute('href')` returns the full address `(http:// .... #tabIdentifier)`, while in other browsers (IE8 included) it returned the actual string in href, namely "#tabIdentifier".

Problem solved by adding a little string processing:

```
 targetId = targetId.substring(targetId.lastIndexOf('#'));
```

Answer (score 0):

do you call that function? And did it work in other browsers? Try this:

```
 function BindResizeSideBar() {
    $("div#containerFloat div#tabs-box a").each (function() {
        var targetId = $(this).attr("href"); // starts with #
        if($("div" + targetId).length == 0) return;
        $(this).bind("click", function() {
          var height = $("div" + targetId).height() + 90;
          alert(targetId + ', ' + height);
          $("div#divSavedSearchesSideBar div.leftSide").height(height);
        });
    });
    // init: click on tabProfile;
    $('div#containerFloat div#tabs-box a[href=#tabProfile]').click();
}
```

In your HTML code, an id is given by an `id` attribute, not by a `#`:

```
<div id="xxxxxx" ...></div>
```

Comment: It functions in IE8 and FF, only IE7 keeps acting crazy.

Comment: The 'html' I posted was shorthand, to give an idea of how the page is structured. So "<div#content-side.searchProspects>" was the short version for "<div id='content-side' class='searchProspects'>"

Comment: oooh... But you should try the code anyway, because the "href" attribute starts with a #, so you don't need to search for "#"+"#href"

Comment: Good catch on 'div#' + '#id'; it actually worked, bizarrely enough, but I replaced it anyhow. For targetId, I used this.href; it gives the full address, but at least it behaves consistently.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong what might be happening is that IE redirects your page to the specified href and in process cancelling any events you're trying to fire on the a tag.